# Read in a text file, splitting by an unsual character and process "line" by line

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm comfortable working with cleanly formatted CSV and tab delimited text files. Unfortunately for me i've been given a badly formatted text file to insert into my mySQL database. I have the data insert sorted it just the reading in of the text file that's causing my issue. Reading in a small version of the file works fine, but the full size (40mb) is causing me timeouts. I'm keen to read in line-by-line if at all possible.

Example of text file content:

```
62800, ,PRODUCT TITLE, BRAND NAME, XXX.XX, XXX.XX, DESCRIPTION OF 
PRODUCT GOES HERE BUT IT DOES FALL ON TO MULTIPLE LINES~ WITH TILDAS INSTEAD OF COMMAS FOR THE MAIN TEXT AND NEW LINES A
T RANDOM POINTS{}
```

The "{}" signifies the end of the record and this repeats throughout the document.

My existing script splits by this ("{}"), but creates an array, I think this is where it's falling over. As the data is so large.

Existing code:

```
$handle = @fopen("WEBDATA2-2.txt", "r"); // productsample..txt
if ($handle) {

while (($buffer = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
$temp_product .= $buffer;

    // If end of file - exit loop
if(strpos($temp_product, 'END-OF-FILE') !== false) break;

$nlcheck = trim(substr($temp_product, -2));

//echo $nlcheck."<br>";
if ($nlcheck=="{}" || $nlcheck=="}") {
  $products[]=explode(',',$temp_product);
  $temp_product="";
  }
}
fclose($handle);
}
```

I'm not sure how best to explain this question. Please let me know if theres anymore information I can give.

Comment: how about increasing the timeout?

Comment: Does "{}" always appear at the end of a line?

Comment: why do you want it do line by line. you can use mysqlimport or you can remove {} with sed

Comment: @FrancisEytanDortort yes each "line" ends with a {}, however its important to mention there are random newlines within the product descriptions

Comment: @BerndBuffen purely because the script times out.

Comment: @dagon for some reason increasing the timeout has no effect. tried both inline with the script and from plesk php ini editor.

Comment: @ABOO if you run the query from command line or from a website.

Comment: @dagon Im running from a website - I guess I should run as a cron? Does that make a difference?

Comment: the time limit on cli scripts ( therefore a cron called script) is 0 (infinite)

Comment: I really did not know that! I'll look up creating a cron for this.

Answer (score 1):

You could just pre-process the file. If every product ends with {} this should do the trick:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/([^}])\n/$1/' foo.txt
```

To explain, `perl` is searching for any line ending that isn't preceded by a "}" and removing it.

Comment: Ok, my level of experience fails me here. How would I run this? Given I have the file and a mac in front of me ?

Comment: Open up Terminal.app and type away. Perl comes built-in to OS X.

Comment: Ok - thanks. I might need more of an understanding to get this to work. is "foo.txt" my output file or input? If so how do I tell it my input? Or does this edit the file? Do I need to type the full path to the file? Sorry - this is very new to me!

Comment: Yes, replace `foo.txt` with the full path to your filename. It will edit the file in place.

Comment: I wasnt able to work with this. I'm hoping to revisit this soon. For now i'm working on a smaller dataset - will update you

Answer (score 0):

Does this suit your needs?

```
if (false !== ($handle = @fopen('WEBDATA2-2.txt', 'r'))) {

    ignore_user_abort(true);
    set_time_limit(0);

    $buffer = '';
    while (false !== ($line = fgets($handle))) {
        $buffer .= $line;

        if ('{}' === substr($buffer, -2)) {
            $product = explode(',', $buffer);

            // process product data here

            $buffer = '';
        } else {
            $buffer .= "\n";
        }
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: This is working on my shortened file - im going to try on the full file. Thank you for your help so far. Much appreciated.

Comment: Sadly this also times out. I'm yet to try running as a cronjob. Hopefully this will fix my issue! Thank you for your help

Comment: Currently you're calling it from a browser?

Comment: Not necessarily. Some background job architectures do use http requests, such as [Zend Job Queue](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server/content/jobs_component.htm) and AWS Elastic Beanstalk's [Worker Tier](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html). But you have to account for it. (I've updated the answer.)